# Can I access my json object in .ajaxSuccess without having to parse it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, coffeescript

I have an ajax call that works well like so (in CoffeeScript);

```
ajaxElement.change ->
  $(this).data('request','initiated')
  $.ajax
    type: 'PUT'
    url: $(this).closest('form').data('update-url')
    data: $(this).serialize()
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (data) ->
      alert(data.name)
```

The alert confirms that data.name has been correctly parsed from the JSON object that was returned from the server. I want to access this in a jQuery.ajaxSuccess call however. I can do this like so

```
$('form.invoice-form').ajaxSuccess (event, xhr, options) ->
  response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
  alert(response.name)
```

and it works fine, but I am wondering if this is not best practice. I'm parsing the JSON twice to get what I want, which is not a huge overhead but probably best avoided. Is there something in one of those parameters in ajaxSuccess that already contains my parsed Javascript object that I have such easy access to in the original .ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

I think the success callback is invoked before the ajaxSuccess callback. So, with that in mind, can you store the json data on the form and do something like the following? *I don't write coffee script, apologies for any syntactical booboos*

```
ajaxElement.change ->
  $(this).data('request','initiated')
  $.ajax
    type: 'PUT'
    url: $(this).closest('form').data('update-url')
    data: $(this).serialize()
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (data) ->
      $(this).closest('form').data('lastdata',data)
      alert(data.name)

//...
$('form.invoice-form').ajaxSuccess (event, xhr, options) ->
    lastData = $(this).data('lastdata')
    alert(lastData.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `success` function do nothing with parsed JSON you can just ommit `dataType` (or set it for `text`) - then jQuery will return simple text, and you will parse it only once (in your second function).